# Proto gRPC Java stub fail while parsing map type

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am building the server-based application based on protobuf with gRPC interface.
Server part - golang
Client part - Java

The proto file has an object (map as type):

```
message SomeResponse {
  map<string, Entity> entity_by_id = 1;
}

message Entity {
  uint32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
}
```

Based on this file generated the Java gRPC stub to make a request to server.
Once I do request to server - client thrown the error:
`CANCELLED: Failed to read message.`

Client code:

```
EntityRequest request = EntityRequest.newBuilder().addExtIds("abc").build();
        EntityResponse response;
        EntityServiceGrpc.EntityServiceBlockingStub client = EntityServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(
                ManagedChannelFactory.get(
                        InfrastructureProperties.GRPC_HOST,
                        InfrastructureProperties.GRPC_PORT
                )
        );
        try {
            response = client.getEntityByExtIds(request);
        }
        catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
            // failing here with CANCELLED: Failed to read message.
}
```

The server part works 100% - I confirmed it with goLang gRPC client and another...

The request from the client (java stub) reaches out to the server, and the server return response, Java stub is not able to parse it...
If I change the object type  - works fine. Problem with map.

Can you give me the direction where the problem could be?

Golang protoc version: v4.22.2
Java protoc version to generate stub: 3.23.3
Java client io.grpc version: 1.56.0

I confirmed the specific problem with parsing map value in response by Java stub

The stack trace (I have try to remove useless lines):

```
Status{code=CANCELLED, description=Failed to read message., cause=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sixt.service.bbb_bbb_extension.api.GuestOuterClass
    at com.sixt.service.bbb_extension.api.GuestByExtIdsResponse$GuestByExtIdDefaultEntryHolder.<clinit>(GuestByExtIdsResponse.java:56)
    at com.sixt.service.bbb_extension.api.GuestByExtIdsResponse$Builder.mergeFrom(GuestByExtIdsResponse.java:471)
    at com.sixt.service.bbb_extension.api.GuestByExtIdsResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(GuestByExtIdsResponse.java:656)
    at com.sixt.service.bbb_extension.api.GuestByExtIdsResponse$1.parsePartialFrom(GuestByExtIdsResponse.java:648)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:86)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:48)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$MessageMarshaller.parseFrom(ProtoLiteUtils.java:242)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$MessageMarshaller.parse(ProtoLiteUtils.java:234)
    at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoLiteUtils$MessageMarshaller.parse(ProtoLiteUtils.java:131)
    at io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.parseResponse(MethodDescriptor.java:284)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:660)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:647)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$ThreadlessExecutor.runQuietly(ClientCalls.java:777)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$ThreadlessExecutor.waitAndDrain(ClientCalls.java:760)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:161)
    at com.sixt.service.ride_user_extension.api.GuestServiceGrpc$GuestServiceBlockingStub.getGuestByExtIds(GuestServiceGrpc.java:397)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$FieldDescriptorProto.getProto3Optional()' [in thread "Test worker"]
    at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FieldDescriptor.<init>(Descriptors.java:1519)
    at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FieldDescriptor.<init>(Descriptors.java:1066)
    at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor.<init>(Descriptors.java:944)
    at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor.<init>(Descriptors.java:657)
    at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.<init>(Descriptors.java:561)
    at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.buildFrom(Descriptors.java:333)
    at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Descriptors.java:440)
    at com.google.api.HttpProto.<clinit>(HttpProto.java:57)
    at com.google.api.AnnotationsProto.<clinit>(AnnotationsProto.java:54)
    at com.sixt.service.ride_user_extension.api.GuestOuterClass.<clinit>(GuestOuterClass.java:183)
    at com.sixt.service.ride_user_extension.api.GuestByExtIdsRequest.internalGetFieldAccessorTable(GuestByExtIdsRequest.java:38)
    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.getDescriptorForType(GeneratedMessageV3.java:139)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.print(TextFormat.java:363)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.print(TextFormat.java:353)
    at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.printToString(TextFormat.java:615)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.toString(AbstractMessage.java:110)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepArgumentWriter.readableFormOf(StepArgumentWriter.java:14)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepNamer.testNameWithArguments(StepNamer.java:42)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepNamer.nameFor(StepNamer.java:19)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.getTestNameFrom(StepInterceptor.java:534)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.notifyStepStarted(StepInterceptor.java:568)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runOrSkipMethod(StepInterceptor.java:208)
    ... 49 more
}
```

Comment: Can you share your client code? This error usually happens when your client protos are incompatible with the response (i.e. you updated protos but did not update the compiled code)

Comment: Hello Dogacel, I have rechecked this a few times - the generated stub is from actual proto file and on client I can see the correct response class.

Updated description with client code ...

Comment: There should be more information in the "CANCELED: Failed to read message" error. If it was generated on the client (likely), then it will have a "caused by" exception with more details.

Comment: @EricAnderson The detailed information was: Can not initialize InnerClassEntity... ... but the class was there. I assume the problem in mismatch of versions proto on server and client could be the reason.

Comment: Please include the exception in the question. That error seems unlikely to be due to mismatched versions.

Comment: @EricAnderson updated the original description with the additional information.

For sure I have checked the class GuestOuterClass it exist in generated stub which I connected with gradle dependency from our Nexus...

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` with `FieldDescriptorProto.getProto3Optional`. This seems likely a protobuf-java downgrade. Gradle should do a good job of choosing the protobuf-java version, so maybe you are overriding it? You should make sure not to downgrade the version of protobuf-java specified by `com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos`. That seems to be the problem.